# Would Energz Gofit or Intex Fitrist work without smart phone?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am not sure if I am asking question at correct community, if yes please guide me. However, my concern is I am thinking to buy Energz Gofit or Intex Fitrist and I have Android phone with Andoid 4.0.4 so will it be compatible or even better if I can use it on my laptop's bluetooth to store data ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

EnergZ Gofit is compatible with Android 4.3 and higher and bluetooth 4.0

FitRist Band is compatible with Android 4.4 and higher

So it's time for a new phone. If they have a program for your laptop then you might be able to get by but, just get a better phone before buying one of those.